# Fatal error when copying wordpress site from server to localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, woocommerce

I've been trying to create a local copy of this wordpress site - [click4taps.co.uk](http://www.click4taps.co.uk/). But even though everything seems to run pretty much fine on the server, on localhost I am getting these code errors, I would have maybe expected a database error if I had forgot something in the setup. I'm not super good at `php` but I can't see anything that out of place in the code the error specifies.

Here is the error message I receive when trying to launch the site in localhost:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'woocommerce_layered_nav_init' not found or invalid function name in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\click4taps\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 406
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_product() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\click4taps\wp-content\themes\bazar\theme\plugins\woocommerce-ajax-layered-nav\init.php on line 59

---

Any feedback on this would be very helpful thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what code people would need to see. I just copied all the files of the wordpress install to my local machine using FTP and download the database. All I changed was the wp-config and them functions to update to run on localhost.

Comment: then ignore my comment before.

Answer (score 0):

Activate your woocommerce plugin

Comment: It should already be active. And even if I needed to I can't get to the admin area because of this error

Comment: Change the name of your plugins file to plugins1 to get your admin back working. When it's working change your folder back to plugins and activate your plugins again - I'd probably activate WooCommerce first.